# How do we edit Realm database using Realm Browser?

Tags: ios, database, realm

I have been working on a workout app, for iOS using Swift. I have to create multiple workout objects (about 300) which vary in names. Hence creating a loop to add names would be difficult.

Hence, I am using Realm Browser to directly edit the default.Realm file, created by my app. Now all the objects are in the file, however when I edit any row's value, and then reopen the database, the changes do not persist.

Is there any other way to do this?

```
class WorkoutSession: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    dynamic var completed = false
    dynamic var note = ""
    dynamic var caloriesBurnt:Int = 0
    dynamic var workoutLengthInString = "0 mins"
}
```

All the sessions go inside the Workout Type Class

```
class WorkoutType: Object {  
    dynamic var workoutTypeName = ""
    let workoutSessions = List<WorkoutSession>()
}
```

Comment: Please post more code so we have a better idea of what's going on. You're not using an in-memory Realm database, are you?

Comment: Do you seed your Realm file from the app bundle and replace your `default.realm` file in the user data on every app launch with that?

Comment: Currently all I am doing is, I create some objects on the first app launch. Then I close the simulator, and open the default.Realm file using the Realm Database reader to check all the objects that are created.                                 I then would like to edit the values in those objects. The problem is when i do edit them through the database browser, and close the file, and then reopen it from the database browser, all the edits I make are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was a bug in the browser. Our update is in the release process. Meanwhile you can get a [prerelease](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/0.96.2.1), which fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense now.

Comment: I am using Version 0.98.5 (66) and this still an issue. I can update values with Realm Browser.

Comment: Hey @Lucho, sorry it's been a while since you posted your comment. Does this issue still persist for you or could you resolve it yourself meanwhile? If it still persists, could you open up either a new question or an issue on the [Realm Browser repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/) describing in detail what's not working for you?

Comment: @marius i will check again and report it when i have a moment. Thanks for the comment.